# Calling a list of tickers in quantmod using R

Tags: r, symbols, quantmod, stock

I want to get some data from a list of Chinese stocks using quantmod.

The list is like below:

`002705.SZ -- 002730.SZ` (in this sequence, there are some tickers matched with Null stock, for example, there is no stock called 002720.SZ)

```
300357.SZ -- 300402.SZ
603188.SS
603609.SS
603288.SS
603306.SS
603369.SS
```

I want to write a loop to run all these stocks to get the data from each of them and save them into one data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
library(quantmod)
library(stringr)   # for str_pad
stocks <- paste(str_pad(2705:2730,width=6,side="left",pad="0"),"SZ",sep=".")
get.stock <- function(s) {
  s <- try(Cl(getSymbols(s,auto.assign=FALSE)),silent=T)
  if (class(s)=="xts") return(s)
  return (NULL)
}
result <- do.call(cbind,lapply(stocks,get.stock))
head(result)
#            X002705.SZ.Close X002706.SZ.Close X002707.SZ.Close X002708.SZ.Close X002709.SZ.Close X002711.SZ.Close X002712.SZ.Close X002713.SZ.Close
# 2014-01-21            15.25            27.79               NA            17.26               NA               NA               NA               NA
# 2014-01-22            14.28            28.41               NA            16.56               NA               NA               NA               NA
# 2014-01-23            13.65            27.78            33.62            15.95            19.83               NA            36.58               NA
# 2014-01-24            15.02            30.56            36.98            17.55            21.81               NA            40.24               NA
# 2014-01-27            14.43            31.26            40.68            18.70            23.99            26.34            44.26               NA
# 2014-01-28            14.18            30.01            44.75            17.66            25.57            28.97            48.69               NA
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `getSymbols(...)` returns either an `xts` object, or a character string with an error message if the fetch fails.

Note that `cbind(...)` for `xts` objects aligns according to the index, so it acts like `merge(...)`.

This produces an `xts` object, not a data frame. To convert this to a data.frame, use:

```
result.df <- data.frame(date=index(result),result)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you finish this part s$signal[x] in your code?

Comment: An alternative to `str_pad` is `stocks <- sprintf("%06d.SZ",2705:2730)`.